# How to get timestamp in minutes using Perl

Tags: perl

I am using Perl for time comparison.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print $fh "End Time : $endTime ";    
print $fh "Before if loop : ", time();    
 # time() gives current time timestamp    
            if ( time() < $endTime ) {    
             print $fh "Inside if loop : ", time();    
             $exitValue = 11;    
               }
```

Currently, i am using  `if ( time() < $endTime )`. Here, `time()` gives timestamp in millisecomds but i get `$endTime` as timestamp in minutes.

I want to compare timestamp in munutes.

How do i get timestamp in minutes?

Comment: time() gives you seconds since the epoch. Do you actually get minutes since the epoch in `$endTime` or what kind of a value is that?

Comment: `time` is the number of seconds since the unix epoch. `$endTime` is the number of minutes since/of what?

Comment: Do you want to round the difference to a number of minutes or do you first want to round the timestamps and then take the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time()` gives you the time since the epoch [in seconds](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time.html).

If you want to have minutes, you can use this:

```
my $time_min = int(time() / 60);
```

[David Cross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7231/dave-cross) justly emphasizes that using `int()` always rounds down. Alternatives include:

- `my $time_sec = sprintf '%.0f', time() / 60;` (Note: uses ["half-to-even"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) rounding)
- use [`Math::Round`](http://search.cpan.org/~grommel/Math-Round-0.07/Round.pm)
- as [FSp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/374430/fsp) suggested, use [`POSIX`'](http://search.cpan.org/~shay/perl-5.20.3/ext/POSIX/lib/POSIX.pod) `floor()` or `ceil()`

Comment: But you probably want to call that variable `$time_min` :-)

Comment: The OP is making some strange claims, so I would be inclined to make sure that he means what he says before blindly tagging along

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions:

- you can multiply `$endTime` by the milliseconds in a minute (i.e. `$endTime = $endTime * 60000`) and later compare it with `time()` as you are doing
- you can take the integer division of `time()` by the milliseconds in a minute (i.e. `if (floor(time() / 60000) < $endTime) ...`). As long as I know, you need to `use POSIX` in order to use `floor`

The first would be my favourite option.